# World Of Warcraft updates

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just reinstalled world of warcraft. I own up to Mists of Pandaria.
Once I tried to start the game it said it had like over 20gb worth of data to download before I could play.

Is there any way to get this data on dvd/bluray as I have a slow connection and a low data allowance??

Comment: Oooh... that's a cup and a half of lemon juice in the eye...

Comment: If WoW works like some other MMOs I've played, if you have a friend nearby who also plays WoW (and has the latest updates), you *might* be able to copy their WoW folder to a disk or thumb drive. And copy the contents of that folder over your installation. Might require verrifying the files after, but it could save a lengthy download. (Also, if you plan to reinstall again in the future, it might be worth backing up your game folder before uninstalling)

Comment: Short answer: No, but Blizzard is just about to / in the process of switching file types such that the whole install thing is way easier.

Comment: To confirm what Trent says WoW does work like that (at least used to when I played a couple years back) so just a straight file copy of the folder would do the trick. @Reven: Wouldn't owning the physical media for Mists of pandaria install most of the data or is there that much additional stuff since then?

Comment: You do NOT need the whole folder. You only need the patch file that is downloaded into WoW/Updates or so. I do not play it anymore, so I can't tell where exactly it is living, but it should be called like patchxxx.mpg. You need someone who has the preload data though. If you copy that file to your computer, that can cut down your data usage drastically and save time to copy the whole 30 gigs that WoW has by now or so.

Comment: This was a mistake; the download has been revised and is now about 9 gig.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said in the comments, the best way is to find a friend/neighbor/acquaintance that owns the game. You can move the WoW installation folder freely between machines and it surely saves time opposed to downloading 20 GB of data.

Another way may be to find someone that is willing to download the client for you. Downloading the client doesn't require an active subscription, just the registration to battle.net, and at the same time you can invite this friend to try the game with the 10-day trial.

Installing from the installation discs instead only saves part of the hassle, since the version available in the boxed version of MoP still has to be updated to the latest version of the game.